# Get Typescript interface property type, given property name only

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript interface with many properties. Without any instance of this interface, I need to determine the type of a given property.

```js
export interface Data {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This is possible using index signature on `Data` with a non-variable string.

```js
type propType = Data['foo']; // propType = 'string'
```

However, it does **not** work using a variable.

```js
const propName = 'foo';
type propType = Data[propName]; // Errors
```

Errors:

- Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
- 'propName' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)

Neither of these errors make sense, because `propName` is definitely a `string` not `any`, and it is not "being used as a type here."

**Update**

As it might be obvious, I was trying to do something impossible. After much fighting, I've finally accepted that uninstantiated interfaces do not and will not ever have property or property-type information at run-time.

This method using `type` will work, but only at compile-time. I approved the answer with the correct syntax.

(Still think the error messages in my question are weird though.)

Comment: Did you try `Data[typeof propName]`?

Comment: I think keyof Data as the type of propName may help - will check it out in a few... Edit: eh, no joy with that...

Comment: @Katie if you could elaborate on what you're trying to do more in a real-world scenario that may help - digging into this, I don't totally understand what you're trying to do. I'm assuming your variable propName will be populated at run time, not hardcoded like in your example. That is part of your problem here, the TypeScript you're writing `type propType = Data['foo']` is for compile time stuff - at run time I'm pretty sure your only option is to use typeof on an initialized object.

Comment: @MrRobboto Thanks for referring me to `keyof` but unfortunately that yields the exact same errors.

Comment: @MrRobboto I'll try to explain the situation better. It's definitely a weird edge case, and I'll have to spend some time coming up with a generic example.

Comment: Yeah, keyof was just my knee-jerk, no joy there. I think the whole run time/compile time thing might make this a non-typescript issue if you are indeed trying to determine a type at run time. TypeScript will have stripped out all type info from output and you are just running JavaScript at that point.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you update this...

Comment: Which typescript version are you using? I've just tested the `keyof` example and it's working fine for me

Comment: @Ileon Yeah I must've been making a typo somewhere, my bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two solutions. Either

```
export interface Data {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

type propName = 'bar';
type propType = Data[propName]; //number
```

or

```
export interface Data {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

const propName = 'bar'; //or let propName: 'bar' = 'bar' (both are type literals)
type propType = Data[typeof propName]; //number (typeof propName is 'bar')
```

Comment: So I'm getting the impression that only a `type` can go in the brackets when accessing `Data` this way. Weird that it works with a `'string'` though.

Comment: @Katie are you sure you're using `const propName = 'bar';`? That's *type literal*, so basically Typescript infers the most narrow type here, which is `bar`, not `string`.

Comment: @Katie http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=24#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEUxkzgG8AoOOdCCALjgGcYpkBzAbkrgCNMoGSAK4BbHmi4BfcuWwQkzOGCgQwAOUwi8AXjgByPlD0c4AelPQ4AG2DxlqjVoYH+euLpdG4ACh4QYABZw-HgwAJ5geFYIqFCYVowAlOThkUoqYAAqEToERJgA2qnAEOjpDprAALom5sJiaD7FpeXqlYiM+oZ6iUA

Comment: @Katie see, it works just fine. There must be a problem with your code. Also, whenever you're dealing with types, don't use values. Hence the `typeof propName` when `propName` is a value.

Comment: @Katie "Weird that it works with a 'string' though" What makes you say that? In both cases, we have used a type: `type propName = 'bar';` and `typeof propName`. See my comment above.

Comment: My bad -- I tried it like 3 times, and must've made typos each time, go figure.

Comment: It's not clear to me what I can do with that type object now. How can I, for exmaple, print out that 'bar' is expected to be type 'number'?